# PhpStorm Vim Emulator Keymap Issue in Windows 11

Tags: phpstorm, jetbrains-ide, ideavim

I just upgraded to Windows 11, and I'm experiencing an issue with PhpStorm's Vim emulator. When I hit certain key combos (E.g. <kbd>Alt + Left Arrow</kbd> twice) my <kbd>Backspace</kbd>, <kbd>Delete</kbd> and <kbd>Arrow keys</kbd> stop working. I checked my selected Keymap, and I was using the default Windows one.

What I've tried:

1. Reverting to default Windows keymap from my custom keymap
2. Using another keymap (like Visual Studio)
3. Turning off Vim emulator

None of these resolve the problem. The keymap normalizes for a bit, but then the issue occurs again and the keys stop working.

Anyone knows how to fix?

Comment: Since I'm not using IdeaVim plugin and do not know what certain commands do there (e.g. maybe you are turning on some special mode) right now I may only suggest to check the IdeaVim Issue Tracker (https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issues/VIM) in case if it's a known issue. Other than that: perhaps other ppl that watch newly added tags may help here.

Comment: I ended up reverting to Windows 10 after posting on Youtrack. I'll wait a bit longer before moving over so that all the bugs are ironed out :)